# How to compute a shared secret for 2 users in algorithm Diffie Hellman using openssl lib c language?

Tags: c, algorithm, openssl, diffie-hellman

I need some help with algorithm Diffie Hellman in openssl
I have prime number (p), generator (g), private key of user A and public key of user B. I need to compute the shared key. I wrote this code, but the code is executed till this line

```
 int dhSize = DH_size(dh->priv_key);
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/dh.h>

const char* userA_PrivateKey = "90ff0";
const char* userB_PublicKey = "9d1a59";
const char* p = "66c2fa";
const char* g = "2";

int main(void)
{
    DH *dh = DH_new();

    BN_dec2bn(&dh->g, g);
    BN_hex2bn(&dh->p, p);
    BN_hex2bn(&dh->priv_key, userA_PrivateKey);

    BIGNUM *pubKeyUserB = NULL;
    BN_dec2bn(&pubKeyUserB, userB_PublicKey);

    //Compute the shared secret
    int secret_size;
    unsigned char *secret;
    printf(" Compute DH_size \n");
    int dhSize = DH_size(dh->priv_key);
    printf(" dhSize = %d \n"); //NOT EXECUTED 
    secret = OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * dhSize);

    if(0 > (secret_size = DH_compute_key(secret, pubKeyUserB, dh->priv_key)))
    {
        printf("error \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have two problems:

1) printf, that prints dhSize is not executed at all

2) I am not sure if I set values g, p, priv key correctly ? Will the function DH_compute_key use my g and p ?

Comment: `printf(" dhSize = %d \n");` lacks an argument for the `%d` format specifier. Please enable compiler warnings.

Comment: I added, but nothing is shown in console. Even if I don't use printf my code is not executed after calculation dhSize. This is the main problem.

Comment: Then use a debugger, I was just mentioning one error I noticed. When you say "is not executed" do you mean the program crashed before then, or the line is ignored and subsequent code is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making silly mistakes:

1. `dhSize` should be typed as `DH_size` (~line 24)
   and `DH_size` function calculates size of `struct DH` given a *`const struct DH *`* you are passing it `dh->priv_key` instead of passing it `dh` (~line 28)
2. Similar mistake in use of `DH_compute_key` (~line 28) third argument should be `dh` not `dh->priv_key`.

Please fix accordingly and try again